# How to configure the Python path in installing pymssql?

Tags: python, enthought, pymssql

I have installed Python 2.7 with [EPD](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) of Academic License in Win7 64bit system.
And I want to connect sql server database via python, so I try to install [pymssql](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymssql).
However, it warned as follow.
How should I fix this issue?
Tks.
[image]

Comment: Stupid and a longshot but try installing regular python first and then just install EDP over it? Obviously EDP misses to install a registry key pointing to Py2.7 or it doesn't install the correct Python version unless you're 100% sure it is Py2.7 and not Py2.6 or some homebrew patch.

Comment: @Torxed : EDP do install python 2.7.3 in C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System\Scripts, The pyCharm IDE can find it, but I don't know why pymssql can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that EDP forgets to install the correct two variables needed for Python libraries to determain which python version is installed.
Remember that EDP most likely packages Python in their own installer rather than using the Python default one?

Check the following registry keys:

- HKLM\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\versionnumber\InstallPath
- HKCU\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\versionnumber\InstallPath